# Xamarin forms Webview via websocket

Tags: xamarin, webview, signalr

I developed xamarin forms application with WebView which routing to page with signalR websocket. And when page is loaded connection doesn't start. I have read about android.webview doesn't support websocket. Can someone give me advice about implimintation of websocket via webview. maybe use custom webview or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read that webview doesn’t allow WebSocket on android version less then 4.0. In my case my webview cached the page that I used before added the WebSocket and when I clear the cache all works fine

Comment: Did it trouble on simulator too? Did you clear the cache for the simulator?

Comment: Trouble was on device

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am having issue on Web view (Xamarin form), iOS simulator. The page loads on web browser and works fine but not in web view.

Comment: I have found a solution with overriding the webview for android implementation with clearcache method , and also helps the webview from 3rd party companies like Xam.Plugin.Webview it has a clearcache out of box